# Same IL code, different output - how is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cil

I have a piece of code, which outputs different results, depending on the C# compiler and the runtime.

The code in question is:

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("alo\0alo\0", "alo\0alo\0\0", false, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
                    Compiling with mono (gmcs)    Compiling with .Net (csc)
Running with mono                           -1                           -1
Running with .Net                           -1                            0
```

How can it output different values, when running with the .Net framework?

(BTW, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx the output should be 0, so mono's answer is incorrect, but that's unrelated to my question.)

Even the generated IL code is (almost) the same.

Compiling with .Net:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       29 (0x1d)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      bytearray (61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 ) // a.l.o...a.l.o...
  IL_0006:  ldstr      bytearray (61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00   // a.l.o...a.l.o...
                                  00 00 ) 
  IL_000b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000c:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo::get_InvariantCulture()
  IL_0011:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.String::Compare(string,
                                                              string,
                                                              bool,
                                                              class [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
  IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_001b:  nop
  IL_001c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Compiling with mono:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      bytearray (61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 ) // a.l.o...a.l.o...
  IL_0005:  ldstr      bytearray (61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 00 00   // a.l.o...a.l.o...
                                  00 00 ) 
  IL_000a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000b:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo::get_InvariantCulture()
  IL_0010:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.String::Compare(string,
                                                              string,
                                                              bool,
                                                              class [mscorlib]System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
  IL_0015:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

The only difference is the two extra NOP instructions in the .Net version.

How is it possible? How can the two output values be different?

Also, if anyone has both .Net and mono installed, can you reproduce it?

EDIT: *I don't care* what the correct result is, and *I don't care* that mono and .Net produces different results. I'll probably never encounter embedded nulls AND sort them AND the sorting order will be important.

My problem is that the same *runtime* (.Net 2.0) produces different results, when *compiled* by different compilers.

EDIT 2: I added a table and tried to clarify the question, it should be easier to understand now.

Comment: .NET 4.0 apparently fixed some bug in the String.CompareTo method: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/05/strings-sorted.html

Comment: Should be an answer dtb, note the embedded nulls probably causing this issue. @Hali: does removing the special characters make the compare succeed?

Comment: The whole point is testing embedded nulls :)
The result I get from other programming environments (C++, Python, Lua): "alo\0alo\0" < "alo\0alo\0\0", as expected.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx :
"Null characters are ignored when performing culture-sensitive comparisons between two strings, including comparisons using the invariant culture."
Counterintuitive, but oh well. It produces the "correct" results when compiling with csc. My question is, why does it behave _differently_, when compiled with mono, even though it's running on the same runtime?

Comment: Because as you say, the runtime doesn't count, the code inside string.Compare does. And that's not part of the runtime but part of BCL. So far Hali didn't mentioned on how did he ensured that in both cases the same mscorlib was used, I presume he's seeing different results because he's using different mscorlib assemblies. Open in ildasm and see the assembly extern entry for mscorlib.

Comment: .assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
For both files.

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is that when you're compiling it with Mono, it's referencing the .NET 2.0 version of mscorlib - whereas when you compile it with VS, it's targeting .NET 4.0.

I may be incorrect about which exact version is being targeted in each case, but that's where I'd look to start with: don't look at the IL for the method, look at the referenced assemblies.

(It may help if you'd say which versions of VS, .NET and Mono you've got installed, btw.)

EDIT: Okay, so if it does the same thing regardless of what version you target, how about running a diff on the results of running ildasm on each version? Compare the whole files, not just the IL for the method call itself.

Comment: I did a dump with ildasm, and actually I found a difference. The VS compiler added a CompilationRelaxationsAttribute to my assembly silently. So I added it explicitly: same results.
The only other differences are the order of methods, code size, offsets etc.

Comment: It's getting weirder and weirder...
I reassembled the dumps using ilasm, and I got 0s for both dumps. I tried with mono's ilasm too, the output is 0.
But if I compile the original C# source with gmcs, I get -1 (running with .Net 2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Is this related to string ordering? See [this](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/05/strings-sorted.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+CodeCodeAndMoreCode+(Code,+code+and+more+code.)&utm_content=Google+Feedfetcher) blog entry by Marc

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just another Mono's incompatibility to .NET (especially in System.String::Compare when handling culture info), so please log a report to inform Novell/Mono team. They can feedback and confirm whether it is desired. If this is a bug, you will know at least when it can be fixed.

http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is determined by the `CultureInfo.CompareInfo`. My guess would be that the `CultureInfo.CompareInfo` is returning different bitmasks on .Net vs. Mono. .Net 3.5 returns `0xff` for when I print `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo`. What does it print under Mono? Compare missing bits to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CompareOptions`. If the bitmasks are the same, then there's a bug in either Mono or .Net in how the culture info is interpreted.

With this in mind, I would highly down there's any observable difference in *your* code, if the disassembly is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that nop (No Operation) asm commands are for commands aligning in memory. This gives CPU chance to load code into internal cache and therefor run it faster. It is pretty standard optimization technique and it seems that .NET compiler does it while Mono doesn't care.

Comment: IL is independent of CPU architecture. The nops are to add explicit sequence points for the debugger. You won't find them in release builds.